# Laravel, search exact same substring in eloquent query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table like this

**Teacher Table**

[image: Teacher Table]

What I am trying to do is to get the row which contains the subjects **1**(or any other number like 7,8 etc.)

This is what I have tried in my controller.

```
public function allTeachers($sub_id) //receiving $sub_id(to be searched)
  {
        $teachers_all=Teacher::where('subjects','like','%'.','.$sub_id.'%')->latest()->paginate(50);
        dd($teachers_all);
    }
```

The problem here is that, I am getting all the rows which contains subjects as '1',e.g. if it is '3,11,22' or '41,5' it gets selected.
But what I am trying to achieve is it should only return where subjects string contains '1' followed by any other number after **','** or '1,2,44,31,23' etc.
I am using laravel, I hope I made the question clear.

Comment: Storing comma separated values in a db column is almost never a good idea. You should normalize your data, create separate entries for each of the values, which makes getting data a whole lot easier

Comment: @brombeer i thought it reduces the number of rows in a table, thus making it an effective approach :D

Comment: public function allTeachers($sub_id) //receiving $sub_id(to be searched)
  {
        $teachers_all=Teacher::where('subjects','like',$sub_id.','.'%')->latest()->paginate(50);
        dd($teachers_all);
    }

Comment: But next time use a many to many relationship by creating a new table

Comment: @spartyboy your query also selects 11,21,31,41 etc

Comment: It will because  11 contains 1

Comment: It _does_ reduce the number of rows but that doesn't make it an effective approach ;)

Comment: Create a new table teachers_subject thats how to fix this

Comment: There is a solution to this but it won't be optimal if there is like 1000rows returned.. would you want that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to your question would be either to use [`find_in_set`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) or `concat` to fill some missing commas and then search for the value:

```
Teacher::whereRaw('find_in_set("' . $sub_id . '", subjects) <> 0')
    ->latest()
    ->paginate(50);
```

or

```
Teacher::whereRaw('concat(",", colors, ",") like "%,' . $sub_id . ',%"')
    ->latest()
    ->paginate(50);
```

That being said, @bromeer's comments hold true in any case. MySQL isn't around comma-separated values in fields. Both examples shown above aren't an ideal solution. You should look into relationships a bit more.

---

I suggest using a many-to-many relationship in your case. For that, create a pivot table called `teacher_subject` and add the relation to your `Teacher` model:

```
public function subjects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Subject::class);
}
```

To find any teachers teaching a specific subject, use `whereHas` like this:

```
Teacher::whereHas('subjects', function (Builder $query) use ($sub_id) {
    $query->where('id', $sub_id);
})->latest()->paginate(50);
```

Comment: This is working Perfectly, I got your point about eloquent relationships ,however can you explain a little what <> 0 is doing in the above (first) method.

Comment: `<>` means not equal to, like `!=`.

Comment: I've added an example on how you could leverage MySQL's relations in Laravel - for good measure.